# How do I store a form data into a Codeigniter session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

How do I store an array() of data from a form into a session in Codeigniter?

I want to store the email data so I can use it to retrieve the first name from the database with the help of the model .

Below is my code, which I can't get working:

```
    public function index()
    {

        if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {

            redirect('admin_panel');
        }

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() !== false) {
            $this->load->model('admin_model');
            // then validation passed . Get data from the base
            $res = $this->admin_model->verify_user($this->input->post('email_address'), $this->input->post('password'));

            if ($res !== false) {
                // person has an account

                $session_data = array(
'id' => $row[0]->id,
'email' => $row[0]->email_address,
);
// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

                redirect('admin_panel');
            }
```

Would be nice to know a proper way of doing this . I am pretty new to Codeigniter, and only recently became familiar with MVC.

---

i am sorry for not giving enough detail. i posted only part of the code. I was only interested in how i would store a login form data into a session and how to retrieve it.

Below is the full code of the controller - nxlogin.php

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Nxlogin extends CI_Controller {

                function __contruct()
                {
                    parent::__contruct();
                    session_start();
                }

    public function index()
    {

        if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {

            redirect('admin_panel');
        }

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() !== false) {
            $this->load->model('admin_model');
            // then validation passed . Get data from the base
            $res = $this->admin_model->verify_user($this->input->post('email_address'), $this->input->post('password'));

            if ($res !== false) {
                // person has an account

                $session_data = array(
'id' => $row[0]->id,
'email' => $row[0]->email_address,
);
// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);


                redirect('admin_panel');
            }


        }

        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
         $sess_array = array(
        'id' => '',
        'email' => ''
        );
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);

        redirect('nxlogin');
    }
}
```

This is my model - admin_model.php

```
    <?php


class Admin_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()

    {

    }

    public function verify_user($email, $password)

    {

          $q = $this->db->where('email_address', $email)->where('password', sha1($password))->limit(1)->get('adminusers');

          if ($q->num_rows > 0) {

            return $q->row();
          }
          return false;

    }

    public function get_data($id)

    {

          $q = $this->db->get_where('adminusers', array('id' => $id));

          if ($q->num_rows > 0) {

            return $q->result();
          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is to store the email into the session array , and then later use it to retrieve data - like full name - from the particular database row that has that email , in the admin_panel.php - controller ; which is the admin main page. the code is:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin_panel extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {

      session_start();
      parent::__construct();


    if (!isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {

        redirect('nxlogin');
      }
    }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('admin_panel');
  }

  public function profile()
  {

       if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']))
       {

     $id = isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']) ;
    $this->load->model('admin_model');

    $data['query'] = $this->admin_model->get_data($id);

    $this->load->view('profile', $data);
  }
  }
}
```

I also saw that you used  this code when storing information into the session array -

```
$session_data = array(
        'id' => $row[0]->id,
        'email' => $row[0]->email_address,
        );
```

why is it $row[0] for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spotted a few issues.

**first.** in your model verify_user() method you are returning row()
CI docs [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows) shows that row() returns an object with the first single results.

**second.** in your Nxlogin controller index() method, your row() is being loaded into $res, but then you reference row[0] which is incorrect. reference your results like
`$res->id` and `$res->email_address`

**third.** you should initialize your session with 
`$this->load->library('session');` in your controller constructor and place it AFTER `parent::__construct();` as documented [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session) where you have mixed this up in Admin_panel controller. or use the [auto-loaded](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)

**fourth.** you have loaded the array against a key in your session. two options, (1) you should call get_data with `$id['id']` in your Admin_panel profile method. or (2) load your array without the key. Nxlogin index() change `$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);` to `$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);` now reference your data with `$this->session->userdata['id']` and `$this->session->userdata['email']` which think what you're after.

**last.** also consider following codeigniters style guide [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html) as your false should be uppercase for clarity.

good luck!

Comment: i am using codeignitor ver 2.2 . i know things are a bit different in the 3 and am considering upgrading or maybe move to laravel.  thanks a lot. was helpful though.